# VBA API call `MeassageBoxA` - keep it “on top” after Worksheet selection. Z option Hanging Hooky stuff?

Tags: vba, excel

**VBA API call `MeassageBoxA` - keep it “on top” after Worksheet selection. Z option Hanging Hooky stuff?**

Hi,
  This pop up using “API calls” is working very well for me. Just one small non perfection for me is that it gets hidden behind the worksheet if I click on the worksheet, like this:
*PopUpHiddenBehindWorksheet.JPG* :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJBdn.jpg
So I position it at the edge, as in that screenshot, then it is not too bad. But it would be great if I could keep this pop up  “on top”, (even after clicking on the worksheet)  like this:
*MyBoxOnTop.JPG*  https://i.stack.imgur.com/knF7m.jpg
I expect it is something to do with the first and last numbers in the 6 numbers in this code line, ( so the 0 and 40)

```
          BOOLoks = SetWindowPosition(wParam, 0, 10, 50, 400, 150, 40)
```

The answer is possibly here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx
( I am still trying by trial and error to get there, but it is very time consuming as  I break things a lot when I experiment with these API things_..)
 _...I got this thing to work as it does currently after a lot of experimenting and I don’t really know what I am doing as I not a computer profi. It was so difficult and strained my brain to do it  that my brain has gone comfortably numb and I thought I would admit defeat and ask for help on this last bit.
The codes below are greatly simplified for the purposes of this post. The Links below give a lot more detailed notes on the codes and their development.
So can anyone modify the codes so that the pop up stays on top after I select the worksheet, **but without**  breaking anything else -  one reason I am using this is that I want the positional ability, which is broken with the `Application.Input` Box Method.  I also want the ability to scroll through a worksheet and make a worksheet selection, which is not possible with the `VBA.Input Box Function`. ( That is still possible with the `Application.Input` Box Method. ) ( I can also change the size of this `MessageBoxA`  which is also a reason for me using it )
Here below are my  current codes (Function Codes must go in a normal code module or the `AddressOf WSbWJrkBkOffHtd` gets naffed off.)
If you copy all codes to a normal code module, and make a worksheet selection, and then run the demo calling code `Sub MainSub()` then I think it will be clear what is going on.
(I often make my  `Private`s , `Public`, and I then have my pop up available everywhere ….. )
 ( I have checked my codes in XL2003, 2007, 2010 on different computers and they always work the same )
Thanks
Alan
( P.s. I **do know**  that I can do this probably easily with a Userform – I will look at that separately later.. I am wanting to have up and running and understand a few options for what I am doing. )

```
    Option Explicit    '
    Rem 1 Pseudo Non Modal MsgBox,   MessageBoxA
    Private Declare Function APIssinUserDLL_MsgBox Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MessageBoxA" (Optional ByVal hWnd As Long, Optional ByVal Prompt As String, Optional ByVal Title As String, Optional ByVal Buts As Long) As Long  '
    '_-          ====  The above is all I need to do so that writing  APIssinUserDLL_MsgBox  in any code in this code module will do something very similar to the VBA  MsgBox.  The main difference is that when it is up, I can still scroll up and down in my Excel Spreadsheet and also select a range.  Application.Input Box shopuld do this but for XL2007+ it is bropken and apparantly flakey
    Rem 2_b)(ii) == To set/change The positional arguments        "Sub Classing a "Window""
    ' The next four lines will tie something on my chain for when you pull it.
    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHooksExample Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal Hooktype As Long, ByVal lokprocedureAddress As Long, Optional ByVal hmod As Long, Optional ByVal DaFredId As Long) As Long
    Dim hHkTrpCrpNo As Long '
    '               Dim BkMkClsTeachMeWnd As Long: Let BkMkClsTeachMeWnd = 5 '
    Private Declare Function GetDaFredId Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetCurrentThreadId" () As Long ' Don't loose the fred, help me keep on track of the focus
    ' Below wipe my chain clean.  Or remove it from something.   Or cancel it. Or Kill it.
    Private Declare Function UnHkWndsHkCodezX Lib "user32.dll" Alias "UnhookWindowsHookEx" (ByVal hHookTrapCrapNumber As Long) As Long '               'Release the Hook           This is used in code in a simple code line like:-      Call UnHookWindowsHookCodEx(hHookTrapCrapNumber)
    '_-         === All of the above in section Rem 2 is required so that I am able to organise that when I use APIssinUserDLL_MsgBox another program (my windows hookProcedure program WinSubWinCls_JerkBackOffHooKterd) is triggered. (It has a habit of being triggered indefinitely so the API program Decared in the last line above will be used to stop that happening).
    '2(d)========== The Final API program below we need to actually do what we want.  (WindowIdentifyinghandle,    zorder         ,   x                ,       y            ,       width         ,     height          ,       zFurtherInfo  ) '_- Most is obvious, except the z stuff
    Private Declare Function SetWindowPosition Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowPos" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal zNumber As Long, ByVal CoedX As Long, ByVal CoedY As Long, ByVal xPiXel As Long, ByVal yPiYel As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long '    This API prog will be called in my hook PROCedure function.  So.. Rem 2a)-c) sets "Bookmark"/ series of "Bookmarks"
    Dim BOOLoks As Boolean '  I don't seem to need this, but as a function, the SetWindowPos is designed to return a value.                 I just liked the idea of writing BOOLochs
    Dim GlobinalCntChopsLog As Long ' I use this to keep track of the copy number of my Hook PROCedure function WSbWJrkBkOffHtd, that is to say check for when that  = 2. If that is the case I do the "unhooking" and Exit the Function

    '  ========================
    Rem 3a)         This is just to demo the idea of a Pop Up User InputBox with range selection alternative with API User 32 dll Programs.                             ' Normally in this section 3a) there would be other stuff and probably lots of it and if I have anything to do with it then it will be very Pretty.. Pretty well disgusting probably.
    Sub MainSub() ' This would be your main coding and would nornally be a lot bigger
    '               Some where in the main code I might want to ask the user to select a range. So to do that I
    Dim RSel As Range ' This is a variable to hold the Pointer to the users range object..
     'Set RSel = Selection ' This line will be needed if you chose to send ByVal.

    ' This is normally all I have to do in any other code to get my Pop up. It is like pseudo  Rsel = Application.InputBox( Prompt:= , Title:= , Default:= , Left:= , Top:= , HelpFile:= , HelpContextID:= , Type:=8 )  '    http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/2146-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%89%E0%A4%97-%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B6-%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%88-%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%AF%D8%B2-%DA%A9%DB%8C-%DA%A9*Trying-Blogs?p=10467#post10467
     Call HangAHookToCatchAPIssinUserDLL_MsgBoxThenBringThatMsgBoxUp(RSel)  '                     In a normal application of the main Theme of all this, this would be the main code line you use to cause a the "Pop Up User pseudo InputBox with range selection alternative with API User 32 dll Programs"

    Dim RSelDotValue As Variant: Let RSelDotValue = RSel.Value: If IsArray(RSelDotValue) Then Let RSelDotValue = RSelDotValue(1, 1) ' Just for the case of a multi cel selecction as i want to demo a value output in a simple messagw box below
     VBA.MsgBox Prompt:="Address check RSel: - It is now " & RSel.Address & "" & vbCrLf & "Da .Value, (Top Left) of the range object is " & RSelDotValue '
    End Sub



    Private Sub HangAHookToCatchAPIssinUserDLL_MsgBoxThenBringThatMsgBoxUp(ByRef RcelsToYou) '    This will byReferral To You, (RSel), the actual Pointer of you the original RSel.
    ' Public Sub HangAHookToCatchAPIssinUserDLL_MsgBoxThenBringThatMsgBoxUp(ByVal RcelsToYou)     The RSel Pointer aint Gone anywhere if you do this. Just a copy of the Pointer is here. This will allow you to change the value as the Pointer or a copy of it will tell you where to go and do that... But in neither this line or the last line case have you sent the range object. If you use this line then you will find that the address of the range object will not change, as that refers to the range object of the copy variable in this subroutine. But that will not change the range object of RSel
     Set RcelsToYou = Selection ' 3c(-i)                                                          Pointer GoneTo -1 WTF
    Noughty:                                            ' 3c(0i)                                                          Pointer GoneTo 0y WTF
    ' 3b) Hang A Hook to catch things like APIssinUserDLL_MsgBox,   ....
    Dim BkMkClsTeachMeWnd As Long: Let BkMkClsTeachMeWnd = 5 '
     Let hHkTrpCrpNo = SetWindowsHooksExample(BkMkClsTeachMeWnd, AddressOf WSbWJrkBkOffHtd, 0, GetDaFredId)   ' (5-pull before flush,  somehow arranges that the function gets called  ,
    ' 3c) Bring APIssinUserDLL_MsgBox up
    Dim Valyou As Variant: Let Valyou = RcelsToYou.Value: If IsArray(Valyou) Then Valyou = Valyou(1, 1) 'For display Value of Top Left of Selection
    Dim Rpnce As Long '
     Let Rpnce = APIssinUserDLL_MsgBox(hWnd:=&H0, Prompt:="Yes,  or No to ReCheck, Cancel for help ", Title:="Selection Check: Address is " & RcelsToYou.Address & "  Value is """ & Valyou & """", Buts:=vbYesNoCancel) ' ' Pseudo Non Modal MsgBox
     Set RcelsToYou = Selection: Let Valyou = RcelsToYou.Value: If IsArray(Valyou) Then Valyou = Valyou(1, 1) 'The code waited until you made one of the three message box options. But in this time you could change the selection object
        If Rpnce = 2 Then Application.Help HelpFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AnyFileName.chm", HelpContextID:=2 '              -----    download this file:  https://app.box.com/s/bx2pkvtemsppscz60rd6f430wm89c6fj This is a “.chm Microsoft Help file” It has the name _ AnyFileName.chm ---  Put in same folder as this Workbook  ---   Check out possible workarounds  ---  https://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/1099015-vba-application-inputbox-option-helpfile-helpcontextid.html#post4827566  ---  you should get this  HelpGetUpBollox.JPG imgur.com/KdKOYWr
        If Rpnce = 7 Then GoTo Noughty ' Option to update the displayed Address and Value in Top Left cell of that range
    End Sub
    Rem 4=============  Below my "HOOk PROcedure" under Sub Class Windows event re - route / diversion after you pulled my chain
    Private Function WSbWJrkBkOffHtd(ByVal lMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long  '    I "set a hook"  which should trigger things similar to my MeassageboxaPopping up
     Let GlobinalCntChopsLog = GlobinalCntChopsLog + 1 '  The idea of this is that  I add 1 on entering and subtract 1 when leaving the function.
        If GlobinalCntChopsLog = 2 Then Let GlobinalCntChopsLog = GlobinalCntChopsLog - 1: UnHkWndsHkCodezX hHkTrpCrpNo: Exit Function ' If I have 2 then that is an indication that recurtion has taken place.
        If lMsg = 5 Then Let BOOLoks = SetWindowPosition(wParam, 0, 10, 50, 400, 150, 44)   '  5 here is the number for a window about to be activated. This is probably the one I want. I
     Let GlobinalCntChopsLog = GlobinalCntChopsLog - 1 '  Every first copy run of the code has the count reduced to 0 so that when it starts again (as the only first copy active) it will be increased to 1 again to indicate it is a run of the function copy 1
    End Function
```

Refs:
http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/2227-VBA-Input-Pop-up-Boxes-Application-InputBox-Method-versus-VBA-InputBox-Function#post10465
[Application.Inputbox [LEFT] and [TOP] not working in Excel Vba. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275692/application-inputbox-left-and-top-not-working-in-excel-vba-why/48704228#48704228)
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?617519-RESOLVED-Excel-InputBox-position-works-in-2003-but-not-2007

And here is a link to a file with the codes in it in normal code module “shgterd”
“VierenPopUpBoxes.xls”  :   https://app.box.com/s/q509uefg1ea83i7hwibd46ril83hsy0y

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> HWND_TOPMOST (-1): Places the window above all non-topmost windows. The window maintains its topmost position even when it is deactivated.

So it should be: `BOOLoks = SetWindowPosition(wParam, -1, 10, 50, 400, 150, 40)`

Comment: Hi Thanks. ..tried  `-1`now on a few different system, computers -it's working :) Sod’s law says it don't work on the system I mostly used,- that’s why I missed it. On the system I mostly use it also mostly works. This is the situation that it does not work: If I have the VB Editor open and click once in the VB Editor, or run the code from the VB Editor, - then subsequently clicking on the spreadsheet will hide the Pop up. ( If I click once on the pop up then once again it stays on top). I don’t see this strange behaviour yet on any other system so it is not a major problem. Thanks. Alan

Comment: P.S. - I should have said, Thanks, that's the Booloks ! :)