# How to center an input box in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**Scenario**

I have an input box by using the following code

```
total = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please key in the total value", Title:="", Type:=2)
```

**Problem**

The input box is appearing randomly at the corners of the screen.

**What I need**

I need this input box align to the center of userform or the screen. Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: [Have you tried setting the `Top` and `Left` properties?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel)

Comment: I didn't try that. But that is a static method. If the screen size and others change based on user computer, position of inputbox will still be off sided. I need the position of input box always centered to the userform or the user computer screen regardless of screen resolution

Comment: You can just calculate it from [Application.Top](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-top-property-excel), [Application.Height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-height-property-excel), [Application.Width](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-width-property-excel), and [Application.Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-left-property-excel).

Comment: @Comintern Okay. Let me try that...

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't answer your question and I will re-open the question :)

Comment: @Comintern Thanks. Your suggestion worked. I will post my answer soon

Comment: @SiddharthRout The answer you quoted is not working. Also I don't think my question is a duplicate of the question you quoted.

Comment: @Comintern I can't post my answer due to this question is locked. Anyway this is how i solved it
`total = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please key in the total value", left:=(Application.Width / 2), top:=(Application.Height / 2), Title:="", Type:=2)`

Comment: I re-opened the question

Comment: Not sure, how your solution is working for you. it doesn't for me :)

Comment: Leaving the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275692/application-inputbox-left-and-top-not-working-in-excel-vba-why) here for future users

Comment: @SiddharthRout For me when i removed `application.`, it is having runtime error. But when i use `application.` then its working. Unlike the post you quoted. Also I used `application.width/2` and `application.height/2` to get top and left values

Comment: The solution is not working always in all screen. Not sure why unstable. I will remove the marked answer. Probably someone else can help this issue

Answer (score 3):

Above issue solved this way

```
total = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please key in the total value", left:=(Application.Width / 2), top:=(Application.Height / 2), Title:="", Type:=2)
```

Gave `left` and `top` properties. It can be found by getting `Application.width` and `Application.height`. Dividing these values by 2 roughly move the inputbox to center regardless of screen size

**Edit 1**

I thought problem solved. But when I used different systems, it is not stable. So hopefully someone can help on this