# Position of input box on active screen

Tags: excel, vba

I have an input box which opens on the main screen display - I would like it to display on the screen that the workbook is open on.  We sometimes will have 2/3 screens.

I have a command button which opens a input msg box where the user will input data, which will then be displayed into a text box.  The issue is that if the workbook is open on the 2nd screen the input msg box is displayed on the most left screen.  I would like it to display on the screen that the workbook is open on.
I have the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Input the Assessment Date into the text box
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Enter Assessment Date Here", "Assessment Date", xpos:=5500, ypos:=5500)

ActiveSheet.Shapes("AssDate").TextFrame.Characters.Text = myValue
```

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276064/16578424